# Adding another array into padded_sequence for LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, data-preprocessing

I am new to making RNN'S. I am making a LSTM model which needs to accept twitter posts as text and sentiment. I am having issues with how to prepare my pre processed data for the model.

I am using tesorflow v 2.12.0.

posts is an array of twitter posts.
sentiment is split into neg,neu and pos.

```py
posts=data['post'].values.tolist()

sent_neg=np.array(data['sent_neg'])
sent_neu=np.array(data['sent_neu'])
sent_pos=np.array(data['sent_pos'])
```

```py
sequences=tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(posts)
maxlen = max(len(seq) for seq in sequences)
padded_sequence = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(sequences, truncating='post', padding='post', maxlen=maxlen)
```

I am using VaderSentiment which returns sentiment of a text and it comes in the form [0,1,2]. Since RNN accepts sequential data, I was wondering how to add the sentiment to the padded data.

`sent_array` is an array with all the sent for each post, where `sent_array[0]` is the sent of `posts[0]`.

Currently I have been adding sent to to the padded data like this.

```py
input = np.concatenate((padded_sequence, sent_array), axis=1)
```

Even though colab lets me run and train this model. When I try to make predictions on my localhost through flask it gives me an error. I am accepting a single text and running vader sentiment on it

This is the code on flask.

```
text = request.get_json()['text']
padded = preprocessing(text)
sentiment_dict = sent_analysis(text) # returns sent in [0,1,2,3] format
print(sentiment_dict)
sent_arr = [value for value in sentiment_dict.values()]
sent_arr.pop() # last value not needed  

sent_neg = np.array(sent_arr[0])
sent_neu = np.array(sent_arr[1])
sent_pos = np.array(sent_arr[2]) 

sentiment_array = np.stack((sent_neg,sent_neu,sent_pos), axis=0)

sentiment_array = sentiment_array.reshape((1, -1))
  
input = np.concatenate((padded, sentiment_array), axis=1) `
```

This returns the following error,

> ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0
> has size 248 and the array at index 1 has size 1

I am wondering if I have pre processed my data correctly on both ends. Thank you in advance for any feedback :)

Comment: wasn't the sentiment your output?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have as input a set of posts with a shape after tokenizing of `(nr. of posts, max_len)`. Now you want to somehow include the sentiment information for each post in its input.

I think there are two ways to do this.

First, you could prepend each tokenised input with its sentiment value, so you would get a new input shape `(nr. of posts, 1 + max_len)`. Here you have to be careful that the sentiment values [0,1,2] don't overlap with values from the tokenizer. So you'd need to figure out which values the tokeniser doesn't use. Probably, [-1, -2, -3] should work.

The other option would be to add the sentiment information after embedding the input tokens. In which case you could again prepend the value or actually sum the sentiment value to the embedded vector (in that case I would rescale the sentiment values to be [-1, 0, 1]).

I think in code it would look something like:

```
temp = np.zeros((padded_sequence.shape[0], padded_sequence[1]+1)) # assumes padded_sequence has shape (n_samples, max_len) 

temp[:, 1:] = padded_sequence

for i in range(temp.shape[0]):
    temp[i,0] = all_sents[0] - 3

padded_sequence = temp
```

padded_sequence now has the sentiment values embedded at the start of every sequence for that post. I do `-3` because the values shouldn't overlap with the tokenisers output values.

Hope, this helps and I understood your question correctly.